# Devexpress error in adding reports in razor mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I am trying to use DevExpress reports in my MVC 3 web application "This application is a normal MVC 3 application not a DevExpress MVC 3 application" using the following tutorial for adding XtraReports http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974

The problem is each time i am trying to add

```
@Html.DevExpress().ReportToolbar(settings => {
// The following settings are necessary for a Report Toolbar. 
settings.Name = "ReportToolbar";
settings.ReportViewerName = "reportViewer1";
}).GetHtml()
```

DevExpress() gives me an error

'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DevExpress' and no extension method 'DevExpress' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

any suggestions?!

Comment: Have you referenced the `DevExpress.Web.Mvc.v12.1.dll` in your project and added the required using `@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI` at the top of your view?

Comment: Yes, I am already adding the reference to the project. In Views when i am trying to add @using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI the same error for DevExpress 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'DevExpress' and no extension method 'DevExpress' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And what happens if you write: `@DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.DevExpress(Html).ReportToolbar(...` ?

Comment: yes, I try that and nothing happened the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the steps provided in this link to manually register Devexpress components to your project:

[How to: Manually Register DevExpress Extensions to Start Using Them in an MVC Web Application](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163)

The only thing missing in the steps provided above was the assembly binding redirect. Without it, I was getting the exception:

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'.]
```

To prevent the error, I added this section to my main web.config under `<configuration>`:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This will redirect older mvc assembly versions to MVC 4. For MVC 3, the bindingRedirect line should be like this:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: The same is true for "MVC 5"